# 'crypto' module: error in Realm function when using verifyAccessToken

Tags: mongodb, okta

We have created a function in Realm Service of MongoDB atlas.

We are passing an okta generated access token to this function to get it verified.

We are using below code in the function

const claims = oktaJwtVfr.verifyAccessToken(’$oktaaccesstoken’,‘api://default’);

But we are getting below error when we call this function.

{
"error": "'crypto' module: error verifying message",
"error_code": "FunctionExecutionError",
"link": "https://realm.mongodb.com/groups/6074931f0ea7xxxx1776f78d/apps/620543aa14c4be86edc27c06/logs?co_id=6210d675xx891e8aa7xx95"
}

We have added ‘@okta/jwt-verifier’ dependency in the code.
Any suggestion please ?

Comment: Have you tried to use their latest `https://github.com/okta/okta-jwt-verifier-js` instead to see if it maybe better/different?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried it. But I get same error.

Comment: Open an issue on GitHub or send a question to developer@okta.com with your issue. Maybe they will help you